# ByteBuddy java agent requires application dependency which is increasing agent jar size

Tags: byte-buddy

I am a writting a java agent using byte buddy, it works great, I am using lot of @Advice.OnMethodEnter annotations to add code to an existing class.

I have the following concern:

- I am adding lot of application/3rd party dependency to the agent,
  which is increasing the size of the agent jar
- I am concerned if I will run into classversion issues etc, if the
  version of application dependency changes.

Can you please suggest if there is a way to avoid adding application dependency to the byte buddy java agent? Looks like in javassist, I can add the code to a method by using eg.

eg.

```
final String reportCode = MetricsCollector.class.getName() +
    ".report(" +
    "\"" + behavior.getLongName() + "\", " +
    "System.nanoTime() - $_traceTimeStart" +
    ");";
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you are not supposed to include the library code in your agent; rather you should compile against the library in a *provided* scope dependency and then use the `AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice` class to let Byte Buddy apply the advice based on your code and the library code that is found on the user's class loader at runtime.